# Adonis serve --dev command is instantly stopped after running in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

Recently i'm trying to using ubuntu 18.04 instead of windows 10.

The same project in adonis, in windows i run the command:

```
adonis serve --dev
```

Now, when i do a adonis serve --dev the command not persist and is like the terminal cancel the nodemon and i can't access my api because the server is not running.

```
renatop@renatop-Aspire-E5-574:~/Área de Trabalho/DEV/bkp/x/x/x$ adonis serve --dev

 SERVER STARTED 

renatop@renatop-Aspire-E5-574:~/Área de Trabalho/DEV/bkp/x/x/x$
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide log file? Its hard to say something with limited info.

Comment: Try reinstall node modules

Comment: This issue is cause by changing node version using nvm, restarting resolve the issue.